# How to place the item bullet at the top of a multiline item?

Tags: lists, vertical-alignment, matrices, itemize

I have the following LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\A}{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}}
\newcommand{\B}{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}}    

\begin{itemize}
\item $\begin{aligned}
BA&=\B \A\\&=\B=\B \A=BA
\end{aligned}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

My poor dot has the following wish:

[image: The poor dot]

How can I fulfill his dream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\begin{aligned}[t]` is your friend ;)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\A}{\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}}
\newcommand{\B}{\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}}    

\begin{itemize}
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
BA&=\B \A\\&=\B=\B \A=BA
\end{aligned}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```